# nullpointer exception on android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i just don't understand why I have a nullpointerexception with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText field;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
    Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    Button moins = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moins);
    Button ctof = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ctof);

    plus.setOnClickListener(buttonclick);
    moins.setOnClickListener(buttonclick);
    ctof.setOnClickListener(buttonclick);

}


private View.OnClickListener buttonclick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.plus:
                //TODO
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, field.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};


}
```

I don't understand my mistake, it's simple and I don't know where is the issue. I can't get my field and print the result.

Comment: What does your nullpointerexception says

Comment: probably one of the views you retrieved by `findViewById` is not in the `activity_main` layout or the name of it is different than those you used to get it.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.example.gon.tp03.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)

Comment: post your layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private EditText field;
```

You defined your edit text

and you've done it again

```
EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
```

Comment: yeah it was my mistake. it's work know. i forgot to delete the second definition.

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have declared your EditText twice.
Remove "EditText" From "EditText field = ......"
the problem will be solved